# Apply fourier series to the function $f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(\cos x)$

Tags: fourier-series

There's function:

$$f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(\cos x).$$

What is it's Fourier series?

I have never worked with this class of functions actually, so I do not know where I should start and how.

Comment: Hint: this is a piecewise constant function.

Comment: It is a periodic function stuck into another function. Maybe it is periodic? If so, what is the period?

Comment: @mathreadler, the period is not given, thats why I am totally confused, otherwise I would start finding $a_0$ $a_n$ and $b_n$

Comment: Ok but what properties do cos(x) and sgn(x) have. Maybe you can use those properties to derive periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

You have $\mathrm{sgn}(\cos(x))=1$ if $x\in ]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$ (mod $2\pi$) and $\mathrm{sgn}(\cos(x))=1$ if $x\in ]\pi/2,3\pi/2[$ (mod $2\pi$).

The function

$$x\mapsto \mathrm{sgn}(\cos(x))=1$$

looks like this:

[image]

You can just apply your formulas for Fourier series, it will work fine. Separate the integrals according to the values $1$ or $-1$ of your function, and the computation will work fine.